# Semi-private Issue Tracking

Tags: git, github, issue-tracking

I'm working on an open source project that requires me to work with a few third parties. Currently I'm using a private bug tracking system to maintain a list of both bugs and feature requests from these third parties, and priorities are assigned allowing me to target the larger issues first. However, I'd like to move to an open source development process and this means opening up this issue tracker up to the public. However, I don't want to share all of these issues (particularly some of the feature requests)

Therefore, is anyone aware of Issue trackers that allow some issues - such as feature requests - to be private while the remainder are public? I've researched this extensively myself but the best approach I've come up with is having two separate systems - public and private - that I manually synchronise (i.e. *public issues -> private issue tracker*) - an approach outlined by GitHub [here](https://help.github.com/articles/issues-only-access-permissions). Surely there has to be something cleverer than this?

Comment: Do you have a budget for this?

Comment: I'm having trouble reconciling "Open source" and "private feature requests". The context of the code changes needs to remain private but the actual outcome/functionality can be available to the world?

Comment: @EduardLuca Yes the budget is there if a suitable tool exists

Comment: @MattC Mostly the feature requests have to do with internal builds or branches targeted towards a specific customer. While these builds are hosted internally I do not want to maintain two different issue trackers - assigning priorities becomes too difficult - hence public and private.

Comment: @stephenfin then check out my answer, it might be what you need, and if your project meets the requirements, you'll even get it for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assembla (with pair of "Tickets" and "Support" tools)
- [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt%3afeatures) with

  - Public / Private Projects - Public project accessible to all users, private are only accessible to those   explicitly added.
  - Public / Private Notes - Private notes are accessible to users with a specific access level to the relevant project.
  - Public / Private Issues - Private issues are accessible to users with a specific access level to the relevant project.

Comment: Mantis looks interesting. Main issue would be whether public/private flag could be set *per issue* rather than *per project* (ideally different subsets of issues would be visible to different users depending on access levels). I will investigate.

Comment: @stephenfin - yes, it can. But not public/private per se, but "visible to which **groups of users**" AFAICR (worked with Mantis long time ago)

Comment: Turns out when you look for "groups" WRT issue trackers, you find a lot of products with support. Bugzilla for example http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/tip/en/html/groups.html. This is definitely the correct approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on an open-source project, you might just [qualify](https://www.atlassian.com/software/views/open-source-license-request) for a JIRA free subscription.

With [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/pricing/?tab=ondemand) you can also have unlimited *Anonymous* users (those are viewers only).

Not sure if this meets your needs, but it's definitely worth checking out, and I think they also have a one month trial.

Comment: Jira also supports groups (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Groups) which means this answer is also correct. Alas I can only nominate one :( Thanks nonetheless

Comment: No worries, I'm not doing this for the reputation. If it helped you or some future visitor, that's good enough for me :)